# React Component, validate the child's component data in paren component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Let's say I have a reactJS component with a render function as something like this:

```
  render(){
    return(
        <div>
          <OnBoardingHeader title={title} subTitle={subtitle} modalFlag={modalFlag}></OnBoardingHeader>
          <OnBoardingStepsHandler  displayContent={this.state.displayContent} modalFlag={modalFlag}></OnBoardingStepsHandler>
          <div className={modalFlag?"onBoarding-modal actions":"ui center aligned container"}>
              <div className="ui  left labeled icon button" onCLick={this.showPrevious}>
                Pre
                <i className="left arrow icon"></i>
              </div>
              <div className="ui  right labeled icon button" onClick={this.showNext}>
                Next
                <i className="right arrow icon"></i>
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    )
  }
```

On click of the Next and the Previous button,  I change the value for `displayContent`, Which says what need to be there in my content section.

```
displayContent is another react component.
```

Now there is a scenario, where before changing this displayContent, I need to access the values inside my `displayContent`.

I mean, let's say we have a form at step one, now on click `next` I want to validate this form, only then proceed to `step two`, in other sense call my next function.

Now, this form has this own validation function which I need to call. Similarly, the other steps have there own validation function which I need to call before I move to the next step.

The scenario is very similar to this,https://gist.github.com/jamesgpearce/53a6fc57677870f93248
except, the control of my `next` and `previous` is with the parent. Not with the child.

Now, My question is how do I access my child's components function inside my parent component. I am not sure if this is advisable to do.
My restriction is, I don't want my next and previous controls with the child.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

I built my own wizard component where your requirements sound similar to what I had to do to it. Basically each child component does its own validation internally and should execute this.props.onValid and this.props.onInvalid along with some useful information you wanna bubble up to the parent after each validation. And as the parent you inject a callback to them to see if the particular content(child) has passed the validation test internally.

```
//parent
export default () => {
  return <Child onValid={onChildValid} onInvalid={onChildInvalid}/>;
}

//child
export default ({ onValid, onInvalid }) => {
  //do validation based on user activity
  //call onValid/onInvalid whenever the validation is done
}
```

You can do a lot more like onDirty etc to see if certain things have even changed or not by the user.

Comment: I get what you are saying. But, here the control is with the parent, he decides when to click next, and then the child's validation starts, based on the response  I do next or no next.

Comment: I thought that's what you wanted... You said you don't want the child to have control with next and prev. So I thought you want the parent to control prev and next.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you specifically need to access the child components?

Pass a handler to the child uses (possible after validating the slide) to navigate. Roughly (very):

In the parent:

```
render = () => {
  // ...
  <SomeChildComponent nextHandler={this.nextHandler} />
  // ...
}
```

In the child:

```
// ...
validate = () => {
    if (whateverValid()) {
        this.props.nextHandler();
    }
}
// ...
```

The parent's `nextHandler` sets whatever state is required, which re-renders, which might show the next slide, show a summary, whatever.

We implemented a front/back/up/down wizard slider using essentially this mechanism, with the slide declarations in a standalone JS object, with either a string or a function to indicate what the next and previous slide components were. (The function option is if we need to check wizard state and go to an arbitrary slide based on current wizard state.)

---

If the buttons *must* be in the parent, then you have an additional step.

*(Again, this is a pretty rough estimate.)*

**In the parent**

```
validationHandler = (isCurrentStepValid) => {
  this.setState({ isCurrentStepValid });
}

nextHandler = () => {
  if (this.state.isCurrentStepValid) {
    // Handle valid state, e.g., advance wizard
  } else {
    // Handle invalid state, e.g., don't advance wizard
  }
}

render = () => {
  <SomeChildComponent validationHandler={this.validationHandler} />

  <NextButton onClick={this.nextHandler} />
}
```

**In the child**

```
isComponentValid = () => {
  return whateverValidationRequired;
}

validate = () => this.props.validationHandler(this.isComponentValid());
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I highly appreciate. According to your answer the next, pre buttons are in the childComponent. My restriction is both these components are in my parent.

Comment: No, the location of the buttons ultimately isn't relevant. I'll update my answer to reflect what I think you're saying. But be wary of generalizing too much to the parent; a wizard slide may require different buttons depending on their local state.