# My child component performs validation, but I need to use that validation in a higher component

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, reactjs

Let's I have a form where I allow the user to fill in and choose some options.

It might look like

```
<MyForm>
    <InputWithValidation />
</MyForm>
```

The component `<InputWithValidation />` performs some validation, say their username has to be a certain length, before this submission can go through.

Right now the way I have this set-up is `MyForm` has a function, `submit()` which I pass as a prop to my `InputWithValidation`. On clicking submit, `InputWithValidation` checks its input, and if its valid, will call `this.props.submit`. It is working fine. However, now I want to add a hotkey to submit the form, so I add the following to `MyForm`:

```
document.onkeyup = function (event) { 
    if (/* keys match what I want */) {
        this.submit();
    }
}
```

However, this won't work, as I've never called the validation on the input. How do I solve this issue for 1 input, and for many inputs? While this is similar to form validation I think the hotkey adds a little more complexity.

I feel my question is similar to this question [Validate the child's component data in parent component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39145971/react-component-validate-the-childs-component-data-in-paren-component) but I am hoping for someone to answer with some sort of best practices for a situation such as this.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: "Right now the way I have this set-up is MyForm has a function, `submit()` which I pass as a prop to my `InputWithValidation`. On clicking submit, `InputWithValidation` checks its input, and if its valid, will call `this.props.submit`." None of this is reflected in the code in your question. Not even the submit button. Please edit your question to include more of your actual code, so we can reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Since your `<InputWithValidation />` class already has access to the appropriate context of this.props.submit(), I recommend moving that event handler to your `<InputWithValidation />` class. You can add it after component mount like this.

```
class InputWithValidation extends React.Component {
    //constructor

    //other functions

    componentDidMount() {
        //add keydown event handler here
            //pass to parent with this.props.submit(e.whatever)
    }

    render() {
        //render function
    }
}
```